# Execute jar file through maven by pulling them from a remote repository

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, artifactory

I have a maven project which I build and deploy on a private remote repository. The code is built through continuous integration pipeline.

This repository is accessible from my remote machine. What I want is to pull the artifact and execute it on this remote machine without pulling the source code for the project.

From what I can understand, one needs a pom file which contains this repo, as a dependency, but is their any other way of doing the same without having to download the sources

Comment: does the jar have dependencies in order to run? Do you need to download all dependencies or just the jar?

Comment: Yes, the dependencies as well. Though I can pack the dependencies in the jar itself.

Comment: 1. It seems not quite what maven is supposed to use for 2. setting up dependencies does not download "sources"  (I believe you mean source code?) of dependency. 3. I guess you can just create a POM (with type `pom` will probably work), declare the dependency for the project you wanna download, and use maven-exec plugin.  I dunno why you would want to do it in Maven though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is possible for you to have just one file to download pushed to Artifactory (I assume you are using artifactory from the tag) it is possible to download the file with a simple http get request (via Artifactory REST API), like curl, or even use the JFrog cli.

I recommend using the CLI: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory

To use Artifactory REST API directly go to:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API

Retrieve Artefact api or Retrieve Latest Artefact can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply download the file using CLI provided that you have maven installed. Below is an example command.

```
call mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:get -DrepoUrl=<your nexus url> -Dartifact=<groupid>:<artifactid>:<version>:jar:jar-with-dependencies -Ddest=<destination>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the exec-maven-plugin ? http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html
That is if you want to do the job with Maven (it is not very clear to me if you do or do not want to use Maven on your remote machine).

Note : repacking the dependencies in your executable jar would not be a good practice. You can still build a distribution archive along with your jar (look at the maven-assembly-plugin https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) and use that archive instead.